# Viewpager show two images, high and low res, screen black during loading

Tags: android, image, background, loading, android-viewpager

one again facing a "strange" problem.

Im using a Viewpager to display 2 separate images (Viewpager contains just a layout and 2 imageviews).
The concept would be, display a low resoltion image from local file cache (immediately) and load the high-res picutre meanwhile and show it.

the problem is: only using low res pictures, pictures are showing immediately and everything perfect, but as soon as high-res pictures are enabled (to be shown),
if the user swipes really fast, the screen stays black for "a short time" (500ms to 1,5s) and low resolution images are never displayed.
just the high-res pictures..

maybe anyone faced a similar problem, any assistance appriciated :) thank you!

ViewPager code:

```
/**
 * Create and add a new page of the image at the given position.
 * 
 * @param collection
 * @param position
 */
@Override
public Object instantiateItem (View collection, final int position) {

    Log.v(TAG, "instantiateItem: pos: " +position);

    final Context context = collection.getContext();


    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(context);
    ImageViewTouch imageView = new ImageViewTouch(context);
    ImageViewTouch imageView2 = new ImageViewTouch(context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    layout.addView(imageView, lp);        
    layout.addView(imageView2, lp);

    imageView.setOnSingleTapConfirmedListener((OnImageViewSingleTapConfirmedListener) context);
    imageView2.setOnSingleTapConfirmedListener((OnImageViewSingleTapConfirmedListener) context);
    imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (position == restorePageNumber) {
        loadBitmap(context, position, imageView, imageView2, restoreZoomLevel);

        Log.w(TAG, "zoom level regocnized for pos: " + position + " resetting...");
        restorePageNumber = Constants.INVALID_INT;
        restoreZoomLevel = Constants.INVALID_LONG;          
    } else {
        loadBitmap(context, position, imageView, imageView2, Constants.INVALID_LONG);
    }

    imageView.setFitToScreen(true);
    imageView2.setFitToScreen(true);

    activePages.put(position, imageView2);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout);


    return layout;
}
```

> ```
> protected void loadBitmap (Context context, int position, 
>   ImageViewTouch imageView, ImageViewTouch imageView2, 
>   float restoreZoomLevel) {
>     Photo photo = getPhotoAtPosition(position);
>     Log.v(TAG, "loading photo. pos: " + position + " id: " + photo.getId());
>     // show small image first
>     if (!(photo instanceof CameraPhoto)) {
>         StorageManager.retrieveBitmapBackgroundWithImageview(context, photo,
>                 Photo.SIZE_SMALL, imageView, true, Constants.INVALID_LONG);
>     }
>     // afterwards replace with big image
>     StorageManager.retrieveBitmapBackgroundWithImageview(context, photo,
>             Photo.SIZE_LARGE, imageView2, true, restoreZoomLevel);
> }
> ```

in Those methods (retrieveBitmapBackgroundWithImageview) Images are loaded in Background, and afterwards set to the imageview.

It seems that it has some problem with setting the large bitmap.
Even if the Imageview with the large bitmap stays hidden (View.GONE), and only local cache images are shown, the ViewPager stays black for some "time" (as above, 500ms to 1.5s) on loading pages, if swiping fast :)

thx :)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean swiping fast to alot of pages it just has problems with loading all those views. Do you cancel/interrupt the loadBitmap tasks that are out of the range of the `ViewPager` (not in view or cache)?

And, do you handle concurrency in threads? If you always want to load the pages that are in the `ViewPager's` view or cache first, you should Override `Comparator` and let it compare on the page. The comparator can be used in a `PriorityBlockingQueue` which can be used in a `Executor`